# drupal 7 custom content snippets... or insert formatted fields inside nodes

Tags: drupal

In Drupal 7 I would like to format the content of the node text a little. For example the node should contain several **tips** or **law citations**. They should always look the same, i.e. be identically formatted.

A tip should contain a small icon image on the left, bold font of smaller size, all surrounded by a red border.

A law citation: again an icon image on the left, then the law contents, then the source in small caps floated to the left.

It sounds like those tips and law citations be a custom content type, only I would like to enable the user to easily insert those tips and law citations into his article, everywhere he needs to. Like inserting an image, which also has fields: width, height, title and so on and those fields are inserted appropriately into html (although invisible, but that's not important)

Is there a method to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly a Drupal question.

You should use some tags' class attributes for tips and citations.

For instance

```
<div class="tips">
Here you tip.
</div>

<div class="law-citation">
Citation
<a href="#">Source</a>
</div>
```

The way how they will look like depends on your CSS (border, font, icon, etc.).

Then you should customize your text editor so users can add tips and citations without writing any html code. I don't know about all text editors, but if you use [BUEditor](http://drupal.org/project/bueditor), it's very simple to add your own buttons (with JS popup too).

Or you can add additional CCK fields and customize them, but in this case all tips/citations will appear only above or below article, not in article.

Comment: I think you are right this is not a Drupal problem... Perhaps it's more about writing appropriate plugin to the favourite wysiwyg editor to achieve this.